# How to reserve left side of activity in Android Q for gestures

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation

What is the correct way to notify Android that I need touches on the left side of the screen for a drawer pull-out? Right now on Q beta 3 it goes back rather than pulling out the drawer. I looked for documentation but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT use systemGestureExclusionRects api for Navigation Drawer or any other controls which would result in opting out the whole left/right edge as this will result inconsistent behavior.

DrawerLayout has out of box support for system gestures. All you need to do is update the dependency to '1.1.0-alpha01' and build against Q.

You can refer to [this devbyte](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ljtz7T8R_Hk&t=4s) and [this I/O session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCHEjeLC_UY&t=26s) for more details.

Comment: Supposedly Seekbars have this built-in opt out too but I'm not seeing it up to b4 of Q....

Comment: True, that is what they say in the video.

It does seem that these are the dependencies you need to add
`implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'`
`implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01"`

However, I don't notice a difference as of now. The back gesture still seems to override the drawer.

Comment: This 'out of the box' behavior is changed in the latest drawerLayout release with "long press + swipe"

Comment: Yup. It worked in 1.1.0-alpha01 but not in 1.1.0-alpha02. @DarShan What is to be long pressed?

Comment: @Vairavan It "works", you just need to try ~25 times to understand how to trigger the gesture, as the long click area is way too thin... Then train for 2h, and you might eventually manage to open your drawer 1 time out of 10. Between this and the 3rd party launchers break, the 3 buttons nav still has a bright future... The worse is on mapping apps like Google Maps: usually the long press triggers an action on the map, so if you miss the drawer you'll do something else.

Answer (score 0):

From [the preview docs on gestural nav](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/gesturalnav#conflicting-gestures), View now has the method `setSystemGestureExclusionRects` https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View.html#setSystemGestureExclusionRects(kotlin.collections.MutableList)

Answer (score 0):

According to Chris Banes (Android Developer Relations at Google):

> The drawer behavior is changing. Users will be able to open the drawer
>   by peeking the drawer, and then swiping. Big benefit is that this
>   works with existing apps with "old" DrawerLayout versions.

You can find an animation of what he's talking about [in his tweet](https://twitter.com/chrisbanes/status/1146050918892412928).

I guess we don't have to do anything, just make sure to update our gradle dependencies. Maybe they will change it again in the next version.